# Cucumber + TestNG + SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, testng, integration-testing, cucumber-java

The runner class:

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = "json:target/cucumber-report.json")
@Test(groups = "slow")
public class RunCukesTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

The step definitions class :

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader=SpringApplicationContextLoader.class,  classes = {Application.class,MarketDataServiceMockConfig.class})
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port=0", "management.port=0"})
@TestExecutionListeners(inheritListeners = false, listeners = {
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
public class MyStepdefs extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

private MockMvc mockMvc;
@Autowired
private FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy;


@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

@Before
public void setUp() {

    wac = (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext) SpringApplication.run(Application.class);


}
```

}

The filterChainProxy and wac are not autowired, why ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use Cucumber and Spring Test with TestNG instead of JUnit, all you need to do is extend `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` in your Step Definition, the rest of the code remains the same.

---

Full Code:

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- TestNG -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>${testng.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Cucumber with TestNG -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Test -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Cucumber with Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Test Executor**

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = "json:target/cucumber-report.json")
@Test(groups = "slow")
public class RunCukesTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

**Step Definition**

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader=SpringApplicationContextLoader.class,  classes = {Application.class,MarketDataServiceMockConfig.class})
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port=0", "management.port=0"})
@TestExecutionListeners(inheritListeners = false, listeners = {
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
// Notice that the class extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests now
public class MyStepdefs extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        wac = (EmbeddedWebApplicationContext) SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber and TestNG are both test frameworks. Cucumber is tool for BDD testing, TestNG is for unit/integration testing. I don't think it makes sense trying to integrate Cucumber with TestNG. It's like integrating JUnit with TestNG.

So if you want to execute Cucumber tests with Spring, there is module `cucumber-spring`.

You will have something like main Tests executor:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format={"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"})
public class RunTests {
}
```

And you will define your steps in classes where you define your Spring context:

```
@ContextConfiguration(YourContext.class)
public class StepDefinitions {
    @Autowired
    private YourBean yourBean;

    @Given("^your given line$")
    public void givenLine() {
         //...
    }

    @When("^your when line$")
    public void whenLine() {
         //...
    }

    @Then("^your then assertions$")
    public void thenAssertions() {
         //...
    }
}
```

After running main class `RunTests`, it will try to find Gherkin files and match them with steps. Doesn't matter how are steps structured across your Java classes.

But I must warn you, Cucumber was designed in Ruby first, so some concepts may seem very weird to Java programmer. Sharing state between steps needs to be done via some class level variable. No duplicate steps are allowed. If you need to share state between steps defined in two different classes, you need to use some global objects.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense trying to integrate Cucumber with TestNG. It's like integrating JUnit with TestNG. -> no, it makes sense as you can use TestNG assertions and tools with Cucumber test description. It is fully compatible (for parallelism for instance). Refer to cucumber doc https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/checking-assertions/?sbsearch=TestNG

Comment: @marie, maybe you didn't notice that this answer was written in 2016. First versions of cucumber-testng started to appear in maven central in 2017. If some answer is outdated, feel free to create separate answer.

Comment: yes sorry, I didn't pay attention to the date. Unfortunately I have no answer to help as I also have issues with cucumber testng and spring boot project

Comment: @luboskrnac cucumber-testng existed in 2016, it was in under the group info.cukes (as were all cucumber packages). Despite that, Cucumber needs test assertions for the Step Definitions, as it doesn't provide them on its own. So it makes sense to integrate Cucumber with TestNG if that is your unit test framework.